# Как вернуть пустой объект вместо возвращаемого типа метода? Java

Tags: java

Есть метод `endpoint`, который должен возвращать всегда 1 объект, но объекта может не быть в базе.
Если объекта нет, то в `response` должен попадать пустой объект: `{}`

Проблема в том, тип метода не даёт возможности сделать приведение пустого объекта к возвращаемому типу.

```
public @Nonnull
    Responses.Profile findById(@Nonnull Context context) {
        var id = id(context).orElseThrow(NotFoundException::new);

        return profileService.findById(id)
               .map(Responses::profile)
               .orElseGet(() -> (Responses.Profile) Responses.emptyObject());
```

Response.Profile:

```
    @lombok.Data
    @lombok.Builder
    public static class Profile {
        public String id;
        public String phone;

        @JsonRawValue
        public String form;
    }
```

Ошибка:

> class java.util.ImmutableCollections$MapN cannot be cast to class app.controllers.Responses$Profile(java.util.ImmutableCollections$MapN
> is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap';
> app.controllers.Responses$Profile is in unnamed module of loader
> 'app')

Comment: Возможно, у вас есть опыт с JS, где такое поведение метода - нормальное. Но в Java так не принято делать. Сделать можно, по идее, но придётся сильно извращаться и получится не очень. Скорее всего вам стоит или вернуть `null` или кинуть ошибку. Если потом это должно будет в JSON преобразовываться, то, в теории, можно так настроить парсер JSON чтобы он не сериализировал `Nullable` поля и на выходе, вернув из метода экземпляр Profile класса он может выглядеть как раз так, как вам надо.

Comment: а что если вернуть Object `Object findById(@Nonnull Context context) {...}`? Оба типа по идее к нему приводятся.

Comment: Как используется `findById`? Его вызывает framework или ваш код? Если framework, то какой используется? Кто сериализует объект в json? Что за класс `Responses` и что такое `Responses.emptyObject()`? Эти ответы нужны, т.к. в java просто так нельзя привести объект к другому (несвязанному с ним) типу.

Comment: Я не рассматриваю сделать возвращаемый тип метода `Object`, 
так как должен быть конкретный тип возвращаемого значения, а под `Object` можно воспринимать всё что угодно.
Используется фреймворк Jooby.
В классе Responses лежат статические классы, их используют контроллеры для возврата клиенту в формате Json. 
Метод `Responses.emptyObject()` возвращает `Map.of()`. Он используется временно.